# Use of pipes in backticks

Tags: bash, pipe, backticks

I'm trying to run a command with a pipe but receive errors:

```
echo abc | `echo "grep a | grep b"`
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: grep: No such file or directory
grep: b: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with the code?

Expected results is for the following command to be executed:

```
echo abc | grep a | grep b
```

With a result of

```
abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but here is what you are doing:

```
echo "grep a | grep b"
```

outputs the string `grep a | grep b`.

This is the output from the backticks.  You are using the backticks in a position where the shell wants a command, so "grep 'a' '|' 'grep' 'b'" is attempted as the command line, with all the tokens interpreted literally (I added single quotes to make this a bit clearer, hopefully) so the shell ignores the input from `echo` and instead attempts to look for the regular expression `a` in the named files.  You apparently have no files named "|", "grep", or "b", so you get an error message.

What you might want is

```
echo abc | grep a | grep b
```

which searches for "a" in the output from "echo", then searches for "b" in the output from the first grep.  Because `abc` matches the regular expression `a`, the first `grep` succeeds, so the matching line is printed; and because it also matches the regular expression `b` it is printed by the final `grep` as well.

To expand a bit on this, try the following:

```
sh$ echo abc; echo bcd; echo xya
abc
bcd
xya

sh$ ( echo abc; echo bcd; echo xya ) | grep a  # print lines matching a
abc
xya

sh$ (echo abc; echo bcd; echo xya ) | grep a | grep b  # print lines matching a and b
abc
```

It is not clear why you are using backticks; if this is not what you are trying to achieve, please explain in more detail what you want to accomplish.

If you want to find lines matching either a or b, try this:

```
sh$ ( echo abc; echo bcd; ) | grep '[ab]'
```

Comment: dont know why, but i assumed that was php code:D i deleted my answer now, as it was irrelevant for this subject

Answer (score 3):

Triplee's explanation is pretty close (if not saying exactly the same thing) to what I think is happening. "Clasic Shell Scripting" [Robbins & Beebe], section 7.8.1, actually have a good explanation of a gotcha which is related to my original question.

If you write

```
listpage="ls | more" 
$listpage
```

then you get a similar problem where '|' & 'more' are treated as arguments to ls. The reason given is that at the point where variable substitution is done by the shell (step 5/10), the original input has already been broken up into tokens (of which | is one) (step 1/10). So '|' loses its special meaning and is treated as an argument.

However, if you write:

```
eval $listpage
```

eval causes the shell to restart back at step 1, where the '|' character is treated as a special token.

Comment: You should definietly avoid `eval` if you can, though. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character is special only if you let the bash parser see it. You quoted it by using "", so it is no longer special, and `grep` thinks you want it to grep the string `a` from the files `|`, `grep` and `b`.

In general, once you escape a special character that is part of the shell syntax, you can't unescape it later (because then there would be no way of dealing with a file that is actually called `|` - not a good idea, but it *is* possible, and bash shouldn't be unable to deal with it.)

The only way to get such a character treated as special again is to resubmit it to an entirely new invocation of the shell interpreter, which is what Robert Martin's solution does.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
$ `echo "grep a | grep b"`
```

Because the backticks don't understand the pipe. Try this alternate that does the same thing:

```
$ echo "grep a | grep b" | sh
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything, by itself. The first grep will be trying to read standard input, but standard input is already tied up to echo the command into the pipe to sh.